# Combo box value depends on the selection of another combo box

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I need to selected item on 1 combobox will show dpending items from this selection in another combobox. I dont use SQL,EXEL, ACCESS or VBA in project. I added items by my self in winforms. it should look sonething like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfG1L.jpg
Thanks a lot for help.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        ' Index 0 is BMW
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange({"X5", "X6", "7-series", "5-series", "3-series"})
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        ' Toyota
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange({"Teana", "Camry"})
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        ' kia
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange({"Rio"})
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The event handler of ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged should set the items of the second ComboBox based on the index selected in the first ComboBox. What's your attempt so far?

Comment: Didnt try anything yet, Dont know with what to start

Comment: Do you know what is an event and how to use it? If not you should first watch some tutorials about events in WinForm.

Comment: all i was thinking to do it like this: If "BMW" selected in combobox1 then combobox2 display 5 items, if Toyota selected then do the same but with another items in combobox2. i should write in eventhandler this, but which method of combobox is respnosible for "if BMW selected" and how to add items on combobox2? ComboBox2.Additem?

Comment: Event is happening every time when action occur. In our case, its combobox selected item change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        ' Index 0 is BMW
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange({"X5", "X6", "7-series", "5-series", "3-series"})
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        ' Toyota

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot man, can you say how use selected value like this: User selected BWM model in combobox2, i need to use this selected value "if combobox selected value = X5 then call xxxxx sub." WHich method do that?

Comment: It's very similar. Either use `If ComboBox2.Text = "X5" Then `, or, if X5 is the first item, `If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then `.

Comment: sorry my fault  ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then - should be combobox1 :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, people like you keeping stackoverflow alive

Comment: Damn, I fixed the answer.

Comment: What i should use to make pop out elements and combobox wildth be bigger?

Comment: Select the element in designer. There should be a properties page which includes width.

Comment: One more qestioun mate, if i want to disable button when combobox2 index isnt selected, what should i do?

Comment: I seriously suggest you to learn reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx). Actually all information you need about .Net is all there on msdn.